# Req.session undefined with express 4 and Redis store, express-session

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, express-session

Can't seem to figure out how to use redis store for sessions with Express 4, some sample code looks like:

```
var express       = require('express');
var app           = express();
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var session       = require('express-session');
var RedisStore    = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
    }),
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session); // undefined! :(
});
app.listen(3000);
```

As you can see the req.session above always seems to be undefined, and obviously unable to store any variables in there...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the most frustrating problems have the simplest answers... Redis client was never installed. Link for anyone in the future - http://redis.io/topics/quickstart :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to start redis. try typing`service redis-server start`  on your server cli. hope it'll help :)